# Argument of type 'string | RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, function, types

I created a function that accepts a `pattern` arg  which could be a `string` or a `RegExp`:

```
filePaths = findPathsDeep(`${__dirname}/test`, /Scene\d.md/)

function findPathsDeep(dir: string, pattern: string | RegExp) {
    // This is where we store pattern matches of all files inside the directory
    let results: string[] = []
    // Read contents of directory
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((dirInner: string) => {
        // Obtain absolute path
        dirInner = path.resolve(dir, dirInner)
        // Get stats to determine if path is a directory or a file
        const stat = fs.statSync(dirInner)
        // If path is a directory, scan it and combine results
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            results = results.concat(findPathsDeep(dirInner, pattern))
        }
        // If path is a file and ends with pattern then push it onto results
        if (stat.isFile() && dirInner.endsWith(pattern)) {
            results.push(dirInner)
        }
    })
    return results
}
```

I think the `or` is being used wrongly? Because I'm getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'string | RegExp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'RegExp' is not assignable to type 'string'.

106         if (stat.isFile() && dirInner.endsWith(pattern)) {
```

Comment: `String.prototype.endsWith` doesn't accept a `RegExp`, so the error message is correct: you're trying to pass a value that's either a string or a regex to a method that only accepts a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call `endsWith` with a string.

Check if it's a string first:

```
if (stat.isFile()) {
    if (typeof pattern === 'string') {
        if (dirInner.endsWith(pattern)) {
            results.push(dirInner)
        }
    } else if (pattern.test(dirInner)) {
        results.push(dirInner)
    }
}
```

In the case of a regex, you'll also want to pass a regex that ends in `$` to match the end of a line - eg pass `/Scene\d\.md$/`.

Note that to match a literal period, you must escape it with `\.`.

You could also decompile the regular expression and add a `(?![\s\S])` to the end of it in order to match the end of the line, then turn it back into a regular expression - but that's a lot more complicated.

(for the general case, you can't just add on a `$` because `$` can match the end of a *line*, not the end of the *string*, if the `m` flag is being used - but if you can expect the pattern to never be multiline, `$` will work)